# Errors while building c# project

Tags: c#, .net

Whenever I try to build my project, I get this error:

> The "Output" task was not found. Check the following:
>
> 1. The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class.
> 2. The task class is "public" and implements the `Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask` interface.
> 3. The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` directory.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. What can I do about this error?

Comment: Please show the code that occur error

Answer (score 0):

Well I had this error what I did was **restarted** my computer and the error was gone

Hope this helps